# Is it possible to import a module from another database?

Tags: marklogic

I'm looking for a way to share code between different app servers running on the same MarkLogic cluster in order to reduce duplication.

For example, on a cluster if we have:

1. A module /S.xqy in database "Shared-modules"
2. A modlule /P.xqy in database "Portal-modules"

Can P.xqy import S.xqy?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different app servers can be configured to use the same modules database.  That accomplishes what you state as your motivation.

But you get just one modules database per app server.

If you want each app server to have its own modules database, then you need to replicate the shared code into each.  With good automated deployment tools that actually shouldn't be an issue.  (Because you shouldn't be editing those files in the modules database directly, but pushing them in via automated scripts which could push into each from one repo.)

Comment: Probably a better way to have phrased my question is, can one app server reference more than one modules database?  

Speaking of good automated deployment tools, what options are there?  We've started with Roxy, but I'm not satisfied with it.